# How to copy the neural network in papers for benchmark experiments?(GAN model)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I want to change the model below:

https://github.com/w86763777/pytorch-gan-collections/blob/master/source/models/dcgan.py

And I want to test the model below:
[image]

So I have to change the code to match the architecture like this picture.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, z_dim, M):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.z_dim = z_dim
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(self.z_dim, 256, M, 1, 0, bias=False),  # 4, 4
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(256, 128, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 3, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
        )

    def forward(self, z):
        return self.main(z.view(-1, self.z_dim, 1, 1))


class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, M):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()

        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            # 32
            nn.Conv2d(3, 32, 5, 2, 2, bias=False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # 16
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 5, 2, 2, bias=False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            # 8
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 5, 2, 2, bias=False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            # 4
            nn.Conv2d(128, 10, 5, 2, 2, bias=False), #128*2*2
            nn.ReLU(True),

        )

        self.linear = nn.Linear(M // 16 * M // 16 * 10, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.main(x)
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x


class Generator32(Generator):
    def __init__(self, z_dim):
        super().__init__(z_dim, M=3)


class Generator48(Generator):
    def __init__(self, z_dim):
        super().__init__(z_dim, M=4)


class Discriminator32(Discriminator):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(M=16)


class Discriminator48(Discriminator):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(M=48)
```

it seems wrong. Because RuntimeError happened: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x40 and 10x1)

As a beginer I guess I have to change some parameters in the model. ANY ONE CAN POINT OUT MY MISTAKES? I guess Generator32(Generator) and Generator48(Generator) are CNN and Resnet. Not so sure. every little steps will be like an obstacles for beginners. So sad.

Comment: and this code is for testing cifar10 data, so channel is 3

Comment: Can you provide a reference to this paper?

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=9381694

Comment: this author provide 3 cnn model which used for mnist cifar3 celeb data. and I try to use the cnn model which put on the cifar dataset. see screenshot in this page or in that paper. that's same. thank you so much but i am so sad because that's not difficult i guess.

Comment: Please provide the full error backtrace as well as the relevant code that produces it.

Comment: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x40 and 10x1) which indicated that something like stride or dims are wrong when I input it

Comment: Yes, that's not what's missing in your code: please provide the ***full error backtrace*** as well as the ***relevant code*** that produces it.

Comment: RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x40 and 0x1)

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback (the complete one in its entirety). It is more manageable if you could edit the question above with such information.